# Assigning a value to a variable?

Tags: php

I'm working on a PHP project and would love to get some help on variables.

I have a function that looks like this:

```
function custom_get_tour_nearest_booking_dates( $tour_id, $limit = 2, $exclude_booked_tickets = false ) {
    $result = array();

    if ( $tour_id < 1 ) {
        return $result;
    }
```

The database holds a set of products, each of these with a unique ID made up by numeric values, like 1233,2355,6532 and so on.

If I want to display the characteristics of one of these products, how do I link the ID to the variable `$tour_id`?

Comment: What database? What products? You don't even populate `$result`

Answer (score -2):

Somewhere you call that method: custom_get_tour_nearest_booking_dates(4);

Like the example above, 4 is the tour_id. Besides that, your method is kinda useless.